# TableRows are empty even though I have created an ObservableList

Tags: hibernate, javafx, scenebuilder

I have an  Hibernate ORM class called Student that I want to show to a tableview. The problem I face now is that the rows are empty and I don't really know why. This is my attempt to solve the problem:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Student> studentTbl;
@FXML
private TableColumn <Student, String>cID;
private ObservableList<Student> studentObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(entityFacadeClass.getAllStudents());
ArrayList<Student> students;

 @FXML
public void populateStudentTable(){
    if(students == null){
   students = entityFacadeClass.getAllStudents();
    }
    studentTbl.setItems(studentObservableList);
    for(Student student : students){
        cID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>(student.getStudentPin()));
    }
    studentTbl.getColumns().setAll(cID);


}
```

And the entity-class Student:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(name = "Student.getAllStudent", query = "select s from Student s")
)
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    private String _studentPin;
    private String _studentName;
    private String _studentAddress;
    private String _studentPhone;

    public Student(){

    }

    public Student(String studentPin, String studentName, String studentAddress, String studentPhone ){
        this._studentPin = studentPin;
        this._studentName = studentName;
        this._studentAddress = studentAddress;
        this._studentPhone = studentPhone;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="s_pin")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public String getStudentPin() {
        return _studentPin;
    }

    public void setStudentPin(String studentPin) {
        this._studentPin = studentPin;
    }
    @Column(name="s_name")
    public String getStudentName() {
        return _studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this._studentName = studentName;
    }
    @Column(name="s_address")
    public String getStudentAddress() {
        return _studentAddress;
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(String studentAddress) {
        this._studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }
    @Column(name="s_phone")
    public String getStudentPhone() {
        return _studentPhone;
    }

    public void setStudentPhone(String studentPhone) {
        this._studentPhone = studentPhone;
    }


}
```

Any clues what I'm doing wrong? I'm not getting any error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertyValueFactory` is a `Callback` that works by reflection. The argument to the `PropertyValueFactory`'s constructor is the name of the property that is used to compute the value to display, not the actual value to display.

So if you do

```
cID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("studentPin"));
```

then for each (populated) row in the table, the table view will look at the `Student` in that row and call `getStudentPin()` to determine the value to be displayed.

For your `populateStudentTable()` method, all you need is

```
@FMXL
public void populateStudentTable() {
    studentTbl.setItems(studentObservableList);
    cID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("studentPin"));
}
```

The second line (`cID.setCellValueFactory(...)`) should really go in the `initialize()` method (or you can even do that directly in FXML).

Your `students` list looks redundant: you can just use the `studentObservableList` if you need to access the data.

Comment: Ohh thanks, I'll try it out and once again thanks for the explanation.